# Meaning of "the perfect size" in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "the perfect size" in the following sentences,

> In the oven he bakes two German chocolate cakes. In tins ***the perfect
>   size*** he bakes three cherry pies.

(Source: The Baker's Dozen by DAN ANDREASEN)

Does "In tins ***the perfect size*** he bakes three cherry pies" mean "In the perfect size tins he bakes three cherry pies" ? Or does it mean "In tins he bakes three perfect size cherry pies" ?

What type of grammar is this type?

Comment: Did you check that you quoted this exactly? It looks as though what was intended is "In tins [that were] the perfect size, he baked three cherry pies." What you quoted is neither idiomatic nor sensible although it may just be a typographical error where "tin" is used instead of "tins."

Comment: After checking, I accidentally wrote tins as tin. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Tin" is one word for a pie pan, and "perfect size" modifies "tins." Thus, the meaning is

> In pie pans that were the perfect size, he baked ...

The author omitted the introductory "that were" from the adjectival clause, a frequent type of ellipsis.